# Can I actually use this snippet of code in my upload form?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

My website has an upload page which has a form and one of the inputs is meant for tags like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class='label' for="artwork-tags">Tags</label>
    <input class='input' type="text" name="artwork-tags" placeholder="Tags" value='{{ Request::old('artwork-tags') }}'>
     @include('partials.invalid', ['field' => 'artwork-tags'])
</div>
```

I then get the tags on the server side using:

```
$tagsRaw = $request->input('artwork-tags');
```

This is where my actual question starts. I found a snippet of code used for tags input styling which separates the written tags in their own containers after you type a comma (,). However, as you can see in the codepen, the tags input is just a:

```
  <div class="tags-input"></div>
```

No form, no inputs, no submit, no nothing. This is why I'm wondering how would I even get the tags that are written inside that div on the server side?

Codepen - https://codepen.io/juliendargelos/pen/MJjJZm

Comment: Incomplete question. Provide the codepen and snipets of your code.

Comment: Strange, I forgot to add the pen I was referring to. Done now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a possible loading problem to me.  I pulled the code and added it to a page and it worked fine.

So... as this may be more a Javascript question, and less a Laravel one, I'd suggest, you pull up your source on the page and make sure you have both the css and the JS loaded.

This is driven by the JS, but you'll need to handle the incoming items on the server side.  Easiest way to set this up is to dump your request object (`dd($request->all()`) and see what variable is coming in specific to the tags.  From the server side, you will need to write code to accept those tags, & see if they already exist. If not, create new one in the database and grab its new ID.  If it exists already, get the exiting tag's ID from the database based on a string match.

Something like:

```
$existing_tags = \App\Tag::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
foreach(//on $request->get('tags')){
  //Loop to see if name is already in $existing_tags[] - if not, create new tag -- if so, pull ID and attach
}
```

The answer to your question of no form, no inputs, etc, is likely that you haven't pulled in the whole js lib or any dependencies *if the above dump doesn't work*. Also, it's not clear from your question what point you are at, but remember, this is only *part* of the form code.  You'll still need to supply the normal Laravel route and the standard rest of the form (e.g. submit button and so forth).